# Cloud functions refuse to access my serverless vpc connector in my shared VPC, why?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-vpc

I have a shared VPC with a cloudSQL instance in it.
In that host project I also have a serverless vpc connector, with id vpc-serverless-connector. It has 10.8.0.0/28 as ip range. I'm deploying my cloud functions with firebase deploy, a patched version (see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/552) where I set up the VPCConnector following this format:

vpcConnector:'projects/MY_HOST_PROJECT_ID/locations/MY_REGION/connectors/vpc-serverless-connector'

The functions are deployed in another project in the same region MY_REGION. That project has been given access to the sharedVPC.

When I deploy, I always get that error:

> Missing necessary permission vpcaccess.connector.use for
> serviceAccount:service-MY_SERVICEID@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
> on project MY_PROJECT.

> Please grant serviceAccount:service-MY_SERVICEID@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
> the roles/viewer role.

> You can do that by running 'gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding MY_PROJECT
> --member=serviceAccount:service-MY_SERVICEID@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
> --role=roles/viewer'

I ran that command multiple times, I checked to be sure and the gcf-admin-robot iam serviceAccount in my firebase related project has all the necessary roles. It currently has: Viewer Serverless, VPC Access Admin Serverless, VPC Access User Serverless, VPC Access Viewer

So what's happening? What am I missing? I can't seem to be able to make that work. My goal is to be able to access the cloudSQL instance in my host-project of my shared-vpc from my firebase cloud functions in another project.

Note: I also tried deploying cloud functions directly without firebase and get the same error. So firebase should not be the issue here.

Comment: Did you create the serverless VPC connector in the host project? What's your region? When you apply the grant command, what is `service-MY_SERVICEID` -> the projectID of the function? what is `MY_PROJECT` -> the host project? Could you try to add when you talk about HOST project or attached project?

Comment: Yes the VPC connector is in the host project. My region is us-central1.
service-MY_SERVICEID is simply of the form  service-655201204748@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com , I'm not sure what 655201204748 corresponds to internally.  
MY_PROJECT is not the host project, it's the project id of where the cloud function is located (is different from the vpc host project). If I talk about the host project I mention MY_HOST_PROJECT_ID.

Comment: `655201204748` is the project number. I guess the host project, right?

Comment: 655201204748 is the project number of my firebase project where the cloud function resides. Not the vpc host project's.

Comment: I also noticed there are no issues creating a cloud function connecting to the vpc serverless connector inside the vpc host project, works perfectly fine. Problem only happens when using cloud functions outside of that vpc host project.

Answer (score 5):

I found the issue.
I forgot to add the MY_SERVICEID@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com from the service project inside the IAM of the host project.
You need to add this email as a member of the host project with the  Cloud Functions Service Agent permissions.
Somehow I missed that part. Now everything works as expected.